# Flutter, setting the background not working

Tags: flutter

In flutter:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Super App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.blue),
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Text("hello");
  }
}
```

I don't see why this is not having the white background I have set with **scaffoldBackgroundColor**. Here is what I obtain...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just declare the `Scaffold` background color but, forgot to use `Scaffold` `Widget` in your code.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: const Text('hello'),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your MyHomePage Like this

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Text("Hello"),);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In MyHomePage widget, wrap Text with with scaffold .
You can refer [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html) from the docs.